# Array formula with if conditions and substraction

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2021

I am searching for a formula solution that would summarize hours based on two conditions (date - column a, activity - column b). More precise, I want to summarize hours of sleep each day with array formula that would include whole column range.

The data looks like this:

[image]

When I define exact range the formula works.

{=IF(A2:A10=I$6;IF(B2:B10="Sleep";(D2:D10)-(C2:C10);0);0)}

But when I try to include whole column it returns 0.

{=IF(A:A=I$6;IF(B:B="Sleep";(D:D)-(C:C);0);0)}

Thank you!

Comment: what version of excel you have?, please indicate it in the tag section. Thanks

Comment: Excel 2021. Added the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **entire column** using an `IF` statement inside `SUM` or `SUMPRODUCT`. It ensures the time differences is only carried out on valid rows of the input data:

```
=SUM(IF(($A:$A=F1) * ($B:$B="Sleep"), ($D:$D + ($C:$C > $D:$D) - $C:$C),0))
```

Then just extend the formula to the right (notice the `$`-notation).

Using `SUM` or `SUMPRODUCT` directly produces an error (`#VALUE!`), for example:

```
=SUM(($A:$A=F1) * ($B:$B="Sleep") * ($D:$D + ($C:$C > $D:$D) - $C:$C))
```

because it doesn't filter first for valid rows where the subtract doesn't produce an error.

Here is the output:

[image: excel output]

**Note**: You need to try for your excel version, for O365 it works, but it has to be tested for an older version.

The calculation for time differences (the parenthesis is required):

```
$D:$D + ($C:$C > $D:$D) - $C:$C
```

Ensures that when the end date represents a time from the next day as it is in row `5`, it adds `1`, to consider the next day. You can achieve the same using another `IF` (longer but may be easier to understand):

```
IF($D:$D > $C:$C, $D:$D - $C:$C, (1+$D:$D) - $C:$C)
```

**Performance**: Please keep in mind @JosWoolley comments below, about performance. Usually, indicating the entire column in the formula instead of a specific range, forces Excel to check all rows (current maximum: 1,048,576). No significant impact for invoking the formula just one time, but for multiple invocations, it will be a significant impact on performance or Excel can even not respond.

Comment: The formula `=SUM(IF(($A:$A=F1) * ($B:$B="Sleep"), ($D:$D + ($C:$C > $D:$D) - $C:$C),0))` will be forced to process more than `6 million cells`, an astonishing amount for a single formula. Entire columns should not at all be used in such constructions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked in Excel 2021. Many thanks for the explanation of the part of the formula. Indeed it wasn't that clear for me in the original statement what it does. Also, for the part of the formula: "=SUM(IF(($A:$A=F1) * ($B:$B="Sleep")...": is the multiply sign enabling for using multiple conditions in IF statement?

Comment: @JosWoolley In general it is inefficient,  but that was the OP ask. For this particular case it works pretty fast. I have used in other situations the entire column and it takes significant time to return the result, but not for this case. I was surprised

Comment: @IgorK yes you can add additional AND condition by multiplication.

Comment: @IgorK, knowing that your excel version is 2021, you can use `FILTER` instead of `IF` as follows: `=SUM(FILTER(($D:$D + ($C:$C > $D:$D) - $C:$C), ($A:$A=F1) * ($B:$B="Sleep"),0))`

Comment: @Jos Woolley: Don't you think that there would be quite a lag if Excel would need to process so many cells? Maybe it somehow only covers the used range. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @VBasic2008 With only one instance of the formula, the lag isn't noticeable. However, you can easily demonstrate that it is processing all 6 million plus cells by opening a new workbook and entering `=SUM(IF(($A:$A=F1)*($B:$B="Sleep"),($D:$D+($C:$C>$D:$D)-$C:$C),0))` into cell `E2` then copying to a modest number of cells, 500 say, e.g. to `E2:AC21`, and then watching Excel churn away. Note that the ranges referenced are empty, yet Excel is still clearly processing all cells down to row 1,048,576. Using all processors, my machine takes nearly a minute to calculate those 500 formulas.

Comment: @JosWoolley You are right. Sorry for not checking myself, it takes over 10s for 100 rows on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this link for some little-known insight from Microsoft.  Microsoft deliberately prevents the use of entire columns in some formulas that internally use arrays:

[Excel Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/arrays-limitations)

In particular, see [this paragraph.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/arrays-limitations#the-entire-column-rule)

Answer (score 2):

If you designate your data as an Excel table then you could use structured referencing, as in the example below
[image: screenshot illustrating SUMPRODUCT solution with structured references]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((Schedule[End]+(Schedule[Start]>Schedule[End]))-Schedule[Start])*(Schedule[Activity]="Sleep")*(Schedule[Date]=I6))
```

but you should recognise that the organisation of your data does not permit the (by-date) analysis you require, e.g. most of the sleep attributable to Jan 22nd is properly attributable to Jan 23rd but that can't be reflected in the summary, as you have treated the end time on Jan 22nd as being 16 hours *before* the start time...

(cells `I7:K7` have the custom number format `[hh]:mm`)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out (the date problem). Is there a solution to this, or should I rewrite the whole dataset sleep end times? Indeed I wanted to make a line graph with days on the x axis, and hours od sleep on y axis.

Structured referencing works well for this particular problem, but it does not work so well when fixed references are needed.